# How to delete a table row by id except specific id

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have atable where I want to delete all its rows except some rows with specific ids.

I did the follwoing:

```
for(var y=0; y<table.rows.length; y++)
  {
    console.log("deleting row "+ y);
    var initialRow=document.getElementById("initial-row");
    if (table.rows[y].id!=initialRow)
    {
      table.deleteRow(y);
      console.log("row deleted");
    }
else continue;
}
```

But this did not work. Any suggestions?
**EDIT:**
Here is the HTML table:

```
<table align='center' cellspacing=1 cellpadding=1 id="data-table" border=1>
<tr id="head">
<th>Name</th>
<th>Type</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>

<tr id="initial-row">
<td><input type="text" id="text-field"></td>

<td>
    <select name="levels-list" id="levels-list">
    <option value="A" id="option-1">A</option>
    <option value="B" id="option-2">B</option>
    <option value="C" id="option-3">C</option>
    </select>
</td>

<td><input type="button" class="add" id="add-button" value="Add"></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

I am adding rows dynamically int the javascript. Then, I need to delete a row, and refresh the whole table as the added rows ids are dynamic. In order to refresh the table, I want to delete all the old rows except the header and the initial row that was in the HTML page originally. Could not do this correctly.

Comment: you are comparing an element id string to an element object. Will never be equal.

Comment: `var initialRow = document.getElementById('')` this does not return you the `id` of that row, it gives you the whole element, in order to get the `id` access its property like you did with `table.rows`  `initialRow.id`

Comment: var initialRow=document.getElementById("initial-row");
    if (table.rows[y].id!=initialRow)

I dont get it why are you comparing "table.rows[y].id" with initialRow
as initialRow will be an object of element if your DOM contains an element with "initial-row" id
whereas id is a string

Comment: Can you write more specific syntax? you mean I can do: `if (table.rows.id !="initial-row")`?

Comment: There is another trap: Removing elements from the list while traversing it can lead to skipping some elements of the list. To prevent this, loop over the list from the last element to the first (reverse order) or remember the elements to delete in some list and then delete those later on.

Comment: @Linux  please check my edit.

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing an element id (a string) to a DOM element object. You can remove the getElementById call and simply do:

```
if (table.rows[y].id!="initial-row")
```